# Cython: Compile all C dependencies

Tags: python, c, cython

I'm trying to write a wrapper for a C library using Cython.

I've created a simple pyx file which uses my C routine.

```
cdef extern from "sel.h":
    void parse_file(const char *file)


cpdef void main(str file):
    file_pybyte = file.encode('UTF-8')
    cdef char*c_file = file_pybyte

    parse_file(c_file)
```

The `sel.c` file imports a C library located in `src` directory which has hundreds of files.

```
// sel.c
#include "src/clib/finder.h"
#include "src/clib/core/core.h"
#include "src/clib/encoding/encoding.h"
```

These initial header files has a lot of another includes inside them.

Every time I'm trying to run a compiled library I'm getting an error:

> Symbol not found: _type_attribute
>   Expected in: flat namespace

The `type_attribute` function is imported inside `src/clib/finder.h` file.

How can I automatically find and compile all dependencies from a C library?

My setup config looks like this:

```
cythonize([Extension("*",
                     ["lib/*.pyx",
                      "lib/sel.c",
                      ],
                     include_dirs=[
                         'lib/src/clib/',
                         'lib/src/clib/include', ],

                     )])
```

I've tried to list all C files in a config, but it doesn't work since this library has a lot of platform specific files.

Comment: Would you be better treating your C library as a separate library with its own makefile that you link against, rather than trying to compile it with your Python extension?

Answer (score 1):

try

```
extern "C" {
    #include "src/clib/finder.h"
}
```

this will include it as  C instead of C++.

the giveaway here was the `_` in the symbol indicating it had C++ name mangling